# Using unique random numbers for a switch statement

Tags: php, random

I need a function or an array that gives me random numbers from 1 - 47, so I can use it for my code below.

```
public function output($question_id, $solution) {
    $yes = ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid == 0) ? 'Ja' : 'Oui';
    $no = ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid == 0) ? 'Nein' : 'No';
    switch ($question_id) {
        case 1:
            $arg = array(
                'main_content' => $this->build_html(1, '01_0429_04_14_Psori_Arthro.jpg', $yes, $no, $solution)
            );
        break;
        case 2:
            $arg = array(
                'main_content' => $this->build_html(2, '02_0342_05_14_Psori_Arthropathie.jpg', $yes, $no, $solution),
            );
        break;
        case 3:
            $arg = array(
                'main_content' => $this->build_html(3, '03_0255_05_14_Psori_Arthropathie.jpg', $yes, $no, $solution),
            );
        break;
    }
}
```

**Example**

This

```
case 1:
    $arg = array(
        'main_content' => $this->build_html(1, '01_0429_04_14_Psori_Arthro.jpg', $yes, $no, $solution)
    );
```

should look somehow like this:

```
case $random_id:
    $arg = array(
        'main_content' => $this->build_html($random_id, '01_0429_04_14_Psori_Arthro.jpg', $yes, $no, $solution)
    );
```

So that means, each case and each first parameter of the function `build_html` should get a **unique** random id.

Of course I could use `rand()` but then it is quite possible that I get duplicated values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you specifically need random numbers from 1 to 47 or rather non-duplicate numbers from/between 1 to 47?

Comment: @Andrew I need 47 random numbers, because I have 47 cases and each of them should be unique.

Comment: Since you know the range, why not just do a loop? By the looks of things you don't really need random numbers in between 1 to 47, you rather need, you know, the numbers between 1 and 47.

Comment: To enumerate from a fixed set of elements in random order without duplication, **shuffle** the set.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like follows:

```
class SamplerWithoutReplacement {
      private $pool;

      public __construct($min,$max) {
             $this->pool = range($min,$max);              
      }

      public function next() {
           if (!empty($this->pool)) {
               $nIndex = array_rand($this->pool);
               $value = $this->pool[$nIndex];
               unset($this->pool[$nIndex]);
               return $value;
           } 
           return null; //Or throw exception, depends on your handling preference
      }

}
```

Use it as:

```
 $sampler = new SamplerWithoutReplacement(1,47);
 //do things
 $value = $sampler->next();
```

The `$sampler` will draw random samples between 1-47 without replacing them in the pool and therefore they'll be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think it should work:

```
$numbers = [];
function genenerate_nr_not_in_list($list, $min = 1, $max = 47) {
    $number = rand($min, $max);
    while (false !== array_search($number, $list)) {
        $number = rand($min, $max);
    }
    return $number;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 47; $i++) {
    $numbers[] = genenerate_nr_not_in_list($numbers);
}
```

With this solution you can generate numbers in each range (`$min` and `$max` parameters). But it should be at least as big as the number of values you need (`$max`).